# `onClick` handler not firing in IE11

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer-11, babeljs, gatsby

I'm building my first GatsbyJS project and have a simple page where content is rendered based on the active button ("currentPage") the user has clicked on. The active button is kept in the component state.

The page works as expected in all major browsers except IE11. I'm wondering if I need a polyfill (or something) to get this to work?

Thanks for any info!

```
// handler in parent component
handlePageChange (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  this.setState({
    currentPage: e.target.value
  })
}

// render of parent component
render () {
  return (
    <div className={styles.clientsRightsContainer}>
      <Buttons
        a={{ label: 'Label A', onClick: this.handlePageChange, value: 'pageA' }}
        b={{ label: 'Label B', onClick: this.handlePageChange, value: 'pageB' }}
    />
}

...

// handler gets passed down to child component Buttons via `a` and `b` props
const Buttons = ({ a, b }) => (
  <div className={styles.container}>
    <button onClick={a.onClick} value={a.value}>{a.label}</button>
    <button onClick={a.onClick} value={b.value}>{b.label}</button>
  </div>
)
export default Buttons
```

Comment: Did you try to bind your functions?.

Comment: Yes the `handlePageChange` function is bound in the parent's constructor

Answer (score 0):

You most propably are missing polyfills - as suggested here https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/8877.

Install it through this:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-polyfill
```

From the docs:

> If you are using ES6’s import syntax in your application’s entry
>   point, you should instead import the polyfill at the top of the entry
>   point to ensure the polyfills are loaded first: `import "babel-polyfill";`

For documentation and using, see this https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/.

Comment: I have `import 'babel-polyfill` as the first line of the entrypoint to the gatsby app, but still no difference in IE. I'm wondering if I'm missing a step in setting up the polyfill, but I do have it set up as described in the docs.

Comment: Did you also install the polyfill? Are there any error messages in the console?

Comment: Yes I've installed and am not getting any error messages in the console.